# Mimicking file requests on my web server

Tags: website, http

I haven't been able to test this extensively yet, so bear with me.

The scenario is like so: I created a temporary file on my web server, downloaded the file, deleted the file. About 3 minutes later I noticed a 404 error for that file. It was never linked, and only existed for a matter of seconds.

So, I started running tests. I created an empty file, navigated to it, deleted it. Again about 3 minutes later, a 404 error for that file. Next, I just typed in a url for a non-existent file. Again 3 minutes later, a 404 error.

I ran a virus scan with Trend Micro Internet Security on my system (which is a 2 week old fresh Vista install, fully up to date) that turned up nothing (not that it rules out the possibility). Interestingly, I am in the Eastern US, the IP for the offender is in Japan.

Does anybody have ideas or suggestions for me to track down why my HTTP requests are being mimicked by somebody in Japan?

Comment: Would ServerFault be better for this question?

Comment: Possibly. I mostly only use StackOverflow, and StackExchange runs alot of sites, hard to keep up with them all.

Comment: Maybe it's your Trend Micro (or some other browser plug-in) doing link-checking (or alike)?  Have you tried Googling the IP?  Does it do this with Trend (and as much other stuff as possible) stopped via MSConfig?  Perhaps try the same tests from different browser, or another computer, to figure out if it's tied to your browser's requests, or to the server.

Comment: Haven't found anything about the IP except its from Japan. I thought about software, but why is it going through Japan? The only thing that starts up is Trend Micro and my touchpad driver. I started doing tests on other computers on other networks, but it stopped for today. It also appears it only happens during a certain time frame each day. Harder to test.

Comment: What makes you think Trend Micro doesn't have servers in [Japan](http://jp.trendmicro.com/jp/home/)? :)

Comment: I just thought it would be odd for them to forward my request from the US east coast to Japan, then have a server there request the same page. What purpose does that serve? And if they are doing it, I am going to stop using Trend Micro.

Comment: Wow. Spent a lot of time tracking it down, turns out it is Trend Micro. They are sending all my requests to a server in California, then somehow routing it to Japan, then re-requesting every url I request. Seems a bit dodgy to me. Might need to get a new virus scanner.